# Why does Android receive corrupt data?

Tags: java, android, web-services

## **on Request SERVER preparing and SENDING whole DATA (json) to Android Client in response**

> `{"property":[{"prop_Age":0,"prop_Area":300,"prop_Area_SqFeet":2700,"prop_Area_Unit":" Yards","prop_AvailableFor":"Sale","prop_Desc":"Ashok Vihar Phase-1, Individual House for Sale, Corner Freehold 300g Plot in (i) Block Ashok Vihar Phase I @rs 15 Cr","prop_ID":341,"prop_LastUpdatedDate":"","prop_Lease_ID":0,"prop_NumOfBaths":3,"prop_NumOfBeds":3,"prop_OnFloor":0,"prop_PostedDate":"2011-08-01","prop_Price":1.5E8,"prop_Title":"Ashok Vihar Phase-1, Individual House fo","propertyImages":[{"imageID":1042,"imageUrl":"http://localhost/barun/images/thumb.jpg","propertyID":341,"type":"thumb"},{"imageID":1043,"imageUrl":"http:////localhost/barun/images/gallery.jpg","propertyID":341,"type":"gallery"},{"imageID":1044,"imageUrl":"http:////localhost/barun/images/full.jpg","propertyID":341,"type":"full"}],"propertyLocations":{"proploc_AddressLine1":"ashok vihar phase .............................`

**ANDROID RECEIVE DATA and read data from response  but  not received original content 

some data truncate from original response
**

```
12-30 17:07:44.599: I/System.out(4348): Buffer data 
is{"property":[{"prop_Age":0,"prop_Area":300,"prop_Area_SqFeet":2700,"prop_Area_Unit":" 
Yards","prop_AvailableFor":"Sale","prop_Desc":"Ashok Vihar Phase-1, Individual House for Sale, Corner Freehold 300g Plot in 
(i) Block Ashok Vihar Phase I @rs 15  Cr","prop_ID":341,"prop_LastUpdatedDate":"","prop_Lease_ID":0,"prop_NumOfBaths":3,"prop_NumOfBeds":3,"prop_OnFloor":0,"prop_P
ostedDate":"2011-08-01","prop_Price":1.5E8,"prop_Title":"Ashok Vihar Phase-1, Individual House 
fo","propertyImages":{"phoneNumber1":0,"phoneNumber2":0,"usr_Email":"","usr_ID":341,"usr_�����������������������������������������
�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������`
```

**ANDROID CODE TO RECEIVE DATA:**

```
int bytesRead = -1;
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
byte[] bufferTest = new byte[1*1024];
try {
    while ((bytesRead = instream.read(bufferTest)) >= 0) {
        String line = new String(bufferTest);
        str.append(line.toString());
    }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Buffer data is" + str);
```

Why does Android client receive data in corrupted format?

Comment: You should further describe the error. And maybe remove all the binary(?) content...

Comment: So.. you are reading from a stream of bytes (using god knows what character set) and dumping that into a String without specifying what the bytes are, not caring about the number of bytes read? What do you expect would happen? Use an `InputStreamReader`, specify the character set and use that instead...

Comment: Please don't close it.The user seems to be new and didnt know what to post.He might edit the question.I had faced a similar issue and i have a solution for it

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.The reason you see garbage data is that you have allocated 1024 bytes, but actual data is much lesser.So rest of the bytes are filled with garbage

You can surely solve it by doing the following

```
   int actual = 0;
   int length = 1024;
   responseBody = new byte[length];
   while ((bytesread < length) && (actual != -1)) {
       actual = instream.read(responseBody, bytesread, length - bytesread); //
       // Logger.log("After is.read(), actual is " + actual);
       if (actual != -1) {
           bytesread += actual;
       }
   }
   String response = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
```

(or, for a solution that works a lot better)

```
// Assuming your character set is UTF-8
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(instream, "UTF-8");
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
try {
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    int count;
    while ((count = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        b.append(buffer, 0, count);
    }
} finally {
   reader.close();
}
String response = b.toString();
```

Let me know what happens.

Comment: i have tried both code but  sometime data come  in :  original content+corrupt content + original content  so i am unable to receive all the original content